# Execute python command in django admin panel

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to execute python command in admin panel or in django view?I. e. if I would like to sync database in my app using a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a [custom admin view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) featuring a form, and when the form is submitted in the view call `django.core.management.call_command`

Remark regarding using a form: As your request will change things at the server-side, a post must be preferred over a get.