# Show management commands in admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-manage.py

Maybe I am just naïve in my expectations, but I cannot find any simple configuration or app that would allow running a Django project's management commands from the admin interface.

Surely allowing commands to be executed remotely without having to shell to the machine is a pretty common thing?

Do you always have to implement it yourself? If so, how do you add to the existing admin site without replacing it entirely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute python command in django admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308917/execute-python-command-in-django-admin-panel)

Answer (score -2):

Management commands are fundamentally different things than admin views views. Management commands take arguments on the command line, can ask for user input interactively, etc. They can also run in situations where the web app can't run successfully (for example running migrations). That can be long, expensive tasks. Or they can be things that you want to run outside of normal user/admin interaction, such as scheduled tasks from from a cron job.

In a way, management commands operate at a lower level than the admin app.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question. I know what they are and what they can be used for. I’m looking for a simple way to be able to call them via some UI in the admin app.

Comment: Sometimes the right answer is "don't do that, it's not a good idea".  You don't have to accept it if you don't like it, but you're really trying to use a screwdriver to drive nails here.